# How to make header view clickable of tableview in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

is there any way to make header view of tableview clickable so that can navigate to another viewcontroller.

[image]

I am trying to make the same design as there is a team "Chelsea" (section header and it is clickable) and which contains 2 cell of different type(both are clickable). so , what approach should I follow to create the same design.
or please suggest any other way for doing this.

Comment: yes put a view on it use UITapGesture

Comment: You can use collcetionview with flowlayout

Comment: @SPatel is collecetionview will solve this problem as there are multiple clickable cell at one row......one team group look like one cell

Comment: one team group = one section

Comment: use supplementary view for header

Comment: adding a _button_ to the table-header-view and handling the event...?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [uitableviewcontroller select header for section](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7750720/uitableviewcontroller-select-header-for-section)

Answer (score 1):

You can implement below methods and in `viewForHeaderInSection:` you can define `UIButton` or you can add tap gesture on `UIView`

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section

-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

Answer (score 0):

header view of tableview are buttons, or you could use tap gesture.

header view has a block property, you could write your business in .

```
optional public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView?
```

And you can use delegate pattern.

There ie no api like

```
optional public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectHeaderAt indexPath: IndexPath)
```

for tableView

like this

```
var callback: (() -> Void)!


var label = UILabel()

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    label.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.do_it))
    label.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

} 

@objc func do_it(){
    callback()
}
```

Comment: how we can target the headerview in tap gesture? @dengApro